# Dealing with large XML files from SOAP

Tags: python, xml, web-services, networking, soap

I'm trying to receive large chunks of data using SOAP WSDL requests (in Python). Actually I'm using suds to do that.

But when the amount of data is large (for example, an XML with >50MB) I get a MemoryError thrown by suds.

There is a "good" way to deal with large amounts of data sent by SOAP? I thought about reading the input as a stream but I still need to get the whole data in the body before processing it because this is a base64 string and I only can decode it when the whole string is received (am I correct?)

Thank you.

Comment: I assume you mean a base64 encoded string inside a soap response? You could decode as you go (every 4 bytes in the encoded string is 3 bytes decoded) but you've still got to deal with the soap envelope in the request and response. I've cheated by scoping the wire to get the soap payload for the request and turned it into a canned string. The response can then be read into lxml (or even run through a sax like parser) to get a more civilized crack at the data.

Comment: Yes, it is a encoded string inside the soap response body. This string after decoded is an XML. There is any difference in terms of memory if I read the response and store it directly to disk and then parse the XML using, for example, lxml? I would like to know how much memory suds needs to handle a XML with >50MB. How can I know that? What is the difference to have suds dealing with a XML with >50MB or have the lxml dealing with the same file? This is not the same amount of memory needed?

Comment: [Check here](http://www.pending.io/python-slots/) for a user with a similar problem. 30M soap resulted in 1.7Gig in memory. He had a lot of small soap objects and fixed the problem using `__slots__` on some of the suds objects (but doesn't show how he did it...). But check his reference to [objgraph](http://mg.pov.lt/objgraph/) which can give you a hint on how to inspect objects.